# How do I connect 2 motherboards (both has a 10Gbps Ethernet port)?

Tags: wired-networking, crossover-cable

The aim is too transfer files in between the 2 computers as fast as possible

I'm thinking using

1. Cutting 1 end of a cat6a/7/8 cable and configuring it for crossover use  (I cannot find a cat6a+ crossover cable)
2. Or using a crossover adapter (something like this adapter from AliExpress: https://a.aliexpress.com/_mseEGiy)

(I don't have a switch that has 10Gbps ports)

Thoughts? Other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried a straight through cable?

Answer (score 3):

Computers haven't needed crossover cables in at least a decade.
Just get a Cat7 cable long enough to reach; set both ends with same subnet manual addresses.
Go.

Comment: OH! I haven't tried a crossover cable in a long time. let me try!

Comment: another question please. Is that a function of the OS or the hardware? (only askin as the other motherboard is a server board from 2008.